# Why did Columbia disintegrate lower into the atmosphere, not during its peak heat phase?

Tags: reentry, failure, heat-shield, shuttle-columbia

Space Shuttle Columbia entered a period of peak heating at 46 mi (74 km) altitude. Before the contact got broken, the temperature on Columbia's wing leading-edges had sunk already (and the heat shield damage was on a wing). Why did the disaster happen despite being past the hardest phase of reentry? During this phase the shuttle broke up more and more, so was this due to the additional damage during the reentry? It eventually disintegrated around 39 mi (63 km) altitude.

[STS-107 reentry timeline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Shuttle_Columbia_disaster#Reentry_timeline)

Comment: I believe your basic premise - cascading damage over time- is fundamentally correct. But also consider - peak heating is one thing, but the breakup was due to massive drag and turbulence at the damage site.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft: IIRC, the proximate cause of the breakup was the failure of the orbiter's hydraulic systems due to the progressive damage inside the wing, resulting in the loss of lateral and directional control and causing the orbiter to tumble and break apart.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The story of the destruction of the orbiter during entry is told in extreme detail in Section 4 of Appendix D.7 of the [Columbia Accident Investigation Board report](https://www.nasa.gov/columbia/caib/html/VOL2.html) Volume 2.<sup>1</sup>

The very short version of the story is that a small plume of plasma entered the wing through the breach in the wing's leading edge thermal protection system, and it took a while for this plume to cause sufficient damage for the wing to suffer structural failure.

The wikipedia link in the question states that at Entry Interface (EI) + 404 seconds, "Columbia entered a 10-minute period of peak heating, during which the thermal stresses were at their maximum."  Let's take a look at what that means.

This graph shows the heating rate on the wing leading edge panel.

[image]

There doesn't appear to be anything special about EI+404 based on this graph. The heating rate continues to increase until ~ EI+620, then plateaus until ~ET+750.

The document records the progression of the damage as the plume ate away at the wing insides:

> - The centerline of the plume contained enough energy to begin melting the exterior of the wheel well wall by approximately 8:54:00 EST (**EI + 594** sec.).
> - By 8:56:16 EST (**EI + 727** sec.), hot gas had penetrated
>   the wheel well wall
> - ... 8:57:19 EST (**EI + 790** sec.) .... This is an indication of extreme heating of both the left outboard tire and the surrounding instrumentation. The tire has significant thermal mass
>   and substantial heating would be required to produce the
>   slight temperature rise. The tire has significant thermal mass
>   and substantial heating would be required to produce the
>   slight temperature rise. By 8:58:56 EST (**EI + 887** sec.), all
>   left main gear inboard and outboard tire pressure and wheel
>   temperature measurements were lost indicating a rapid progression of damage or wire burning inside of the wheel well.
> - The side-slip angle changed sign at 8:59:36
>   EST (**EI + 927** sec.) indicating that vehicle loss of control
>   was imminent..
> - main vehicle aerodynamic break-up occurred at 9:00:18 EST (**EI + 969** sec.),

So to directly address the question: **Why did Columbia disintegrate lower into the atmosphere, not during its peak heat phase?**:

*It was still within the peak heat phase, even by the wiki definition (EI+404 seconds + 600 seconds = 1,004 seconds). It broke up at EI+969 seconds.*

<sup>1</sup> At least for me the pdfs on this page do not work when clicked. I have to download them first to a file, then open them. If I just click them, I get a scrambled ASCII file.

Comment: Your link returns 404.

Comment: @forest it works for me. https://imgur.com/iuGLbBK

Comment: Odd. I think this might be a case of a website that _should have_ responded 403 (due to my use of a proxy). I never would have expected nasa.gov to make this mistake. If the website had geo-restrictions or blocked proxies, 404 is simply the wrong error code for it to return.

Comment: @forest some NASA website are geo-restricted unfortunately. I will look for a more generic site that hosts the CAIB report. Thanks for letting me know.  BTW, NASA's website management is pretty terrible.

Comment: @forest: Have you tried looking for an archived copy in the Wayback Machine?  Oftentimes you can still access the Wayback Machine's copy of something that you're blocked from viewing directly.

Comment: @forest: Addendum - the directory page _itself_ works, but all the PDFs bar one are irretrievably corrupted (and apparently have been for several years - the most recent good versions in the Wayback Machine are from April 2013).

Comment: @Vikki for me at least, the pdfs at the link in the question still work, but only if I download and then open them. Attempting to open them from the link gives me a giant ASCII data dump.